# What's the difference between ASP.NET and C#?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net

What's the difference between ASP.NET and C#?

Is ASP.NET the original ASP language ported into the .NET framework and C# is an independent language that also uses the .NET framework?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

C# is a [CLS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/12a7a7h3.aspx) programming language designed for the .NET framework. ASP.NET is part of the .NET framework allowing you to write web applications using any CLS compliant language such as C#, VB.NET, F#, ...

What you are referring to *original asp language* is called Classic ASP and it is not a language. It is a framework for developing web applications using VBScript and JScript languages. It is now considered deprecated technology and Microsoft recommends using ASP.NET for developing new applications.

Answer (score 10):

This is a bit broad.  Basically, ASP.NET is a web delivery mechanism that runs either C# or VB.NET in the background.  C# is a programming language that runs ASP.NET as well as Winforms, WPF, and Silverlight.  There isn't really a comparison here.

Comment: I disagree. Visual Studio --> New Project. The two are presented in much the same way and I can totally see how someone would be confused.

Comment: @William Mioch:  Sorry, I wasnt' meaning to say that I didn't understand where the OP was coming from.  Instead, I just meant that the two don't compare.  I was answering the question.

Answer (score 2):

ASP.NET is a Framework.

Web Form divided into two pieces: the visual component and the logic. Visual components are developed using web server controls (markup language), logic developed using csharp or vb

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/428509ah.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zsyt68f1.aspx

Web server controls include traditional form controls such as buttons and text boxes as well as complex controls such as tables. They also include controls that provide commonly used form functionality such as displaying data in a grid, choosing dates, displaying menus, and so on